# Do I need to pool ManagedChannel instances for a multithreaded Java GRPC (1.1.2) client?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

TL;DR

Does grpc-java's `ManagedChannel` have an implicit connection pool or is the pooling of `ManagedChannel` instances the responsibility of the user?

---

So, I am using java grpc 1.1.2 with protoc 3.2.0. It seems to me that there's no implicit support (as of now) for connection pooling that grpc provides for clients. It seems, however, that the abstraction of a connection in grpc, i.e. the `ManagedChannel` object does indeed work with multiple TCP connections. Is that correct? If so, does the `ManagedChannel` come with connection pooling along with it? If that is the case, I probably don't have to worry about the connection pooling, given that the channel is thread-safe and I can simply use a single `ManagedChannel` instance across my client. However, I might indeed have to pool these channel objects too for greater throughput if need be. Is there such an implementation (pooling of channels) that does this for me in grpc itself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, ManagedChannel does the connection pooling, and you only need one.  It will automatically create and destroy connections as they are needed.

Comment: Hi there, is there any source for this statement? Thanks.

Comment: I am a gRPC core contributor and am authoritative on the subject.

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you for your answer, given my tests and current understanding on how gRPC works I know that you are right and I believe on you. Although for a formal documentation for a system it would be nice to have your/this statement in a documentation page so we could link to it :)

Comment: If you send a PR with where you would expect this to be stated I can review it.  Unfortunately since I I know how the system works, I don't know where users look for information first.  (I assume SO would be that place!)

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo What are the configuration options of `ManagedChannel`, and where are those documented?

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo: Hey, your statement seems to be different than one made by Eric. Please see his comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764891/grpc-make-high-throughput-client-in-java-scala

Comment: Does every request will create a new Connection? How can I limit connection count

Answer (score 6):

Since you said you wanted pooling for greater throughput, I assume you want to create and pool multiple connections for one address in a channel. It was not supported, as the channel impl used to create only one connection per address. With the LBv2 which will soon supercede the old version, it's now possible with a custom [LoadBalancer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.1.2/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/LoadBalancer2.java) in which you can [create](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.1.2/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/LoadBalancer2.java#L333) as many `Subchannel`s for a connection as you wish.

You can refer to the stock [pick-first](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.1.2/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/PickFirstBalancerFactory2.java) and [round-robin](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.1.2/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/RoundRobinLoadBalancerFactory2.java) LoadBalancers on how to write your own LoadBalancer.

Comment: i've inspected interface (for create statement) and 'm confused. actually we need a logical group of connections to the same address (for example this is a service within a mesh, so pods already balanced), not subchannel per EquivalentAddressGroup.